# Create index on calculated value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have [a table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3a582/2) with `sales` records by `year` as follows:

```
id year sales
1  2001 10
2  2002 20
3  2003 30
```

I'm joining the table to itself in order to get a `sales_difference` from one year to the next:

```
SELECT s1.*, s1.sales - s2.sales AS sales_difference
FROM sales s1, sales s2
WHERE s1.year = s2.year + 1
```

This query runs pretty slowly, so I want to create an index on `year + 1`. According to [the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html) you can create indexes on expressions such as:

```
CREATE INDEX test1_lower_col1_idx ON test1 (lower(col1));
```

So I try doing this:

```
CREATE INDEX sales_year_plus_one on sales (year + 1);
```

which gives me:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "+"
LINE 1: ...sales_year_plus_one on sales (year + 1);
                                              ^
```

Why is this particular expression not allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose your expression in an additional set of parentheses:

```
CREATE INDEX sales_year_plus_one on sales ((year + 1));
```

See this excerpt from the documentation:

> The syntax of the CREATE INDEX command normally requires writing parentheses around index expressions, as shown in the second example. The parentheses can be omitted when the expression is just a function call, as in the first example.

Comment: Very well spotted. How odd that such a vital piece of information is so subtly tucked away in the small print of the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a window function to get the same effect without the additional index (and thus the overhead of maintaining that index):

```
SELECT *, sales - lag(sales) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS sales_difference
FROM sales;
```

A simple index on `year`, which you probably already have, will suffice here.

Comment: This is amazing. I guess this probably counts as some sort of best practice for this sort of task. But care must be taken around the `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER` as you have to take account of all the other fields in your query (clearly in this dumb case, that's not necessary.)

Comment: Using a self-join means two table scans, window functions get by with a single scan. Do an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on both queries to see the difference. And as with all SQL queries, except the most trivial, care must *always* be taken in getting it right.

Comment: You have to see the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see the performance difference for both queries. http://explain.depesz.com can help